# Node server to echo POST/URL parameters in real time

Tags: ajax, node.js, arduino

I'm working on a project where I'm sending temperature data via Arduino to a Node server. Arduino sends data to the server through URL parameters:

```
http://localhost:3000/submit?temprature=25
```

I'm then fetching the posted data using the following Node server.js

```
var express = require('express');
url = require('url');
var app = express();
app.get('/submit', function(req, res){
  var data = url.parse(req.url,true).query;
  console.log(data);
});
app.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

I'm able to show the required data with `console.log()`, but what I want is, as soon as Arduino sends the data through URL parameters, that data should automatically echo/print on the server: `http://localhost:3000/index.html` like in real time. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Just to be sure, you want that the temp will be printed in another *client* getting the url `index.html` ? the complicated way can be a socket for example http://socket.io/  on just you can store the value on your server and index.html can fetch the value each second for example

Comment: Yes, I want to echo it for all clients connected. similar to what socket.io does with web-socket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `socket.io` to emit events every time the temperature is updated by your arduino device:

```
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);  //pass a http.Server instance
server.listen(3000);  

app.get('/submit', function(req, res){
  var data = url.parse(req.url,true).query;
  io.emit('temperature', data);
  res.send('Temperature Updated to: ' + data.temperature);
});

app.get('/index', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
});
```

Then on the client side, you can listen for events and update the information. This is `public/index.html`:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Socket.IO Temperature Example</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.3.5.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-alpha1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <h1 id="temperature"></h1>

    <script>
      var socket = io('http://localhost:3000');
      socket.on('temperature', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        $('h1#temperature').html(data.temperature);
      });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```